# Validation using javascript and regular expression not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

. Here is my code. I am trying to validate email,but nothing is happening when clicking on validate button. Please reply.
It's not showing message and i don't know why it is not showing.
It is not a complicated code :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>




    function validateEmail(email) {
  var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  return re.test(email);
}

function validate() {

  $("#result").text("");
  var email = $("#email").val();
  if (validateEmail(email)) {
    $("#result").text(email + " is valid :)");
    $("#result").css("color", "green");
  } else {
    $("#result").text(email + " is not valid :(");
    $("#result").css("color", "red");
  }
  return false;
}


$("#validate").bind("click", validate);

    </script>


</head>





 <form>
  <p>Enter an email address:</p>
  <input id='email'>
  <button type='submit' id='validate' >Validate!</button>
</form>

<h2 id='result'></h2>
```

Comment: You should probably bind `validateEmail`, since there is no `validate`

Comment: sorry ,but then also it wont work

Comment: Also open developers console and check errors there

Comment: how open console>

Comment: How can I debug my JavaScript code?
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code @user7441072

Comment: Your edited code is working as expected: https://jsfiddle.net/wx7Lp3c7/

Comment: Use $(document).delegate("#validate", "click", validate); instead of 
$("#validate").bind("click", validate);

Comment: The code actually works as is: https://jsfiddle.net/4dky43xk/

Comment: i tried it ,but not working

Comment: why same code not working for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting your script tag at the bottom of your body, or putting your bind code in the onLoad hook.

The way your code is structured at the moment, your bind code runs before the elements in the body are loaded, ie it binds to elements that don't exist. The reason it works for other people is probably because the load order is browser-dependant. So if re-ordering your code still doesn't work, it would be interesting to know what browser you are using.

Comment: a working example of the above answer https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/20344/